# How to set disabled dates on datepicker by formula?

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I have this code:

```
if (v.name == 'WISH_DATE') {
          const statusDate = moment(this.validAddress.duedate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
          const minDate = moment(statusDate).add(5, 'days');
          const maxDate = moment(statusDate).endOf('month').add(1, 'day');
        
          v.setup = {
            disableUntil: {
              year: minDate.year(),
              month: minDate.month() + 1,
              day: minDate.date()
            },
            disableSince: {
              year: maxDate.year(),
              month: maxDate.month() + 1,
              day: maxDate.date()
            }
          };
        }
```

So what i want to achive is this:
date is enabled if > status_date+5 and date is enabled if< last_day_of_month(status_date)+1

so if i have for example 19/06/2023 i need to enable from 25/06/2023 until end of month, but if its 30/06/2023 then it neeed to be enabled in next month from 06/07/2023 until end of month.
My code now works only if date is not for next month..so any suggestion how can i fix it to work for both solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look at your problem, and I wonder if simply adding `2` to the `minDate.month()` wouldn't be enough for `disabledSince.month`? It works for both 19/06 and 30/06: https://jsfiddle.net/wlecki/fzLcg16o/

```js
const statusDate = moment(this.validAddress.duedate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
const minDate = moment(statusDate).add(5, 'days');
let maxDate = moment(statusDate).endOf('month').add(1, 'day');

v.setup = {
  disableSince: {
    year: maxDate.year(),
    month: minDate.month() + 2,
    day: maxDate.date()
  },
  disableUntil: {
    year: minDate.year(),
    month: minDate.month() + 1,
    day: minDate.date()
  }
};
```

Theoretically, you could get rid of `maxDate` calculations, but I left it in case of, for example, end of year dates like `30/12/2023`.